# Retrieve HIViewRef from dialog

Tags: macos, dialog, webkit, macos-carbon

Is there any way to retrieve a HIViewRef reference from a Dialog (similar to HIViewGetRoot) in order to use it as a browser using WebKit API?

Thank's for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using modern NIB-based dialogs (and not the ancient resource-based stuff with Dialog Manager calls), there's basically no difference between a "dialog" and a "window", so the "HIViewGetRoot" technique applies in dialogs too.

(and if you are still using resource-based dialogs, check out the [upgrading to the Mac OS X HIToolbox](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Upgrading_HIToolbox/Upgrading_HIToolbox.pdf) document, because you'll need to use NIB-based compositing windows if you want to embed a WebView in Carbon.)